# Find $x$ when $x^2\equiv y\bmod p$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Given $p$ is prime and $y$ is a constant. What's the fastest possible way to find $x$ where $x^2\equiv y\bmod p$?

Example: $x^2\equiv97\bmod101$ would give us $x=81$ as one of the solutions. What's the fastest way to compute any one of the solutions of $x$?

Constraints:

1. $0\le p\le10^9$
2. $0\le y\le p$
3. $0\le x<p$

Comment: Note:  $10^2\equiv-1\bmod101$ and $2^2\equiv4\bmod101$, so $(\pm20)^2\equiv-4\equiv97\bmod101$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard approach to compute square roots modulo primes is the [Tonelli–Shanks algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm).

Comment: Thank you for your comment I'll look into it!